# Separar coluna de DataFrame em lista

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Tenho um DataFrame com três colunas:

```
 Categoria Label   Porcentagem
 Cat1      Label1  40
 Cat1      Label2  10
 Cat1      Label3  25
 Cat1      Label4  25
 Cat2      Label1  50
 Cat2      Label2  50
 Cat3      Label3  100
```

Preciso transformar a coluna de Porcentagem em lista, preservando as 4 entradas do Label, por Categoria, do tipo:

```
 lista_porcent = [[40, 10, 25, 25],
                [50,50,0,0],
                [0,0,100,0]]
```

Como fazer?

Valeu!!!

Comment: por favor, mostre qual o output desejado

Comment: Output é lista_porcent = [[40, 10, 25, 25],
                [50,50,0,0],
                [0,0,100,0]]

Comment: então você quer uma lista como output e não um novo dataframe com uma coluna nova, certo?

Comment: isso mesmo! preciso separar a coluna de porcentagem de acordo minhas 3 categorias, manter as 4 entradas de label (preenchendo com zero caso não tenha os 4 labels para a categoria), e transformar isso em list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O que você precisa é de um `pivot_table`:

```py
table=pd.pivot_table(data=df,index='Label',values='Porcentagem', columns='Categoria').fillna(0)

print([table[k].to_list() for k in table.columns])
```

Output:

```
[[40.0, 10.0, 25.0, 25.0], [50.0, 50.0, 0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0, 100.0, 0.0]]
```